# How to check if something was echoed in php?

Tags: php, echo, buffering, ob-start

I'm working on a project based on some custom CMS wherein display blocks are returned by CMS's module when I call it. These blocks are drawn using custom functions I've defined across different files. Certainly, `ob_start()` is used already in CMS itself to preserve the output string. Now, as I see, some of the inner blocks (drawn by the function called by the CMS's module) are drawn only when certain conditions are met (eg, date). So, in some cases, only the outer wrapper of block (`div`) are drawn as the called function echoes nothing.  Now, I want to edit that module by checking if the function echoes something.   My problems is that I cannot use something like this:

```
     $temp = ob_get_contents();
     ob_flush();
     ob_start();
     eval(trim($block->detail));//this is where custom function is called in module
     $block = ob_get_contents();
     ob_flush();
     ob_start();
     echo $temp;
     if($block)
     {
      echo $start.$block.$end;//$start and $end contains div wrapper html
     }
```

The reason is that this `VIEW` module is called several times within same components to draw blocks based on different conditions. Doing like what I did above, draws the formerly echoed html (before the view module was called) several times. I'm still stuck at how to avoid that multiple time echoing of the same html.
I know this problem is bit complicated but any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to flush the previous ob_..., you can just nest multiple ob_start() together!

Comment: Would that skip to buffer the common output buffered already?

Comment: Yes! http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php
"Output buffers are stackable, that is, you may call ob_start() while another ob_start() is active. Just make sure that you call ob_end_flush() the appropriate number of times. If multiple output callback functions are active, output is being filtered sequentially through each of them in nesting order."

Comment: Okay. Let me check. Just a minute.

Comment: I've answered with some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll write a real answer here.
Like I said, you can nest multiple ob_start() together.

Check the php.net manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php
After the warning message.

> Output buffers are stackable, that is, you may call ob_start() while another ob_start() is active. Just make sure that you call ob_end_flush() the appropriate number of times. If multiple output callback functions are active, output is being filtered sequentially through each of them in nesting order.

So your code could be:

```
ob_start();
eval(trim($block->detail));
$block = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
if($block){
    echo $start.$block.$end;
}
```

And that's all, you don't have to stop and start the output buffers again.

**EDIT:**

Or you can even leave the `ob_end_clean()` ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php )

Like this:

```
ob_start();
eval(trim($block->detail));
$block = ob_get_clean();
if($block){
    echo $start.$block.$end;
}
```

Comment: Let me check.. Just a min.

Comment: The layout is getting distorted or probably I'm missing something so I'm  gonna mark it as answer.. :)